# How are List and List<String> different?

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, linked-list

I'd just started working with lists and wanted to know how both of these are different? 
Im guessing the second one specifically points out that it contains only string type stuff, while the first one is more flexible.

But then if the first is more flexible, why do people use the second one ever?

Comment: "If the first is more flexible, why do people use the second one ever?"  Because flexibility often isn't a good thing: it means you aren't sure what is in the list, and it's easier to shoot yourself in the foot by losing track.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called generics.

The second one specifies this is a list of Strings and will throw a compiler error if you try to put something else.

It is useful to prevent people from putting anything besides a String in the List.

Here is a link to the java generic [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).

Answer (score 2):

`List<E>` : Its generic and `E` will be any object i.e it will contain List of Object.

`List<String>` : The data type of list is string i.e it can only contain String.

It depend on the requirement what is the need of datatype of List.May be whatever example you looked require list of String.